# Whats the equivalent for android onHandleIntent() in titanium

Tags: android, titanium, intentservice

Is there any equivalent API in titanium for android `onHandleIntent()` ?

Comment: Do you want to consume an intent ?

Comment: yup. Actually I need to consume an intent when my app is closed.